# Mix two AUNodes in Spotify iOS SDK

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio, spotify

I'm trying to use the dynamic processor and a bunch of filters to compress a specific frequency band within the spotify method `connectOutputBus` but when i mix the nodes in the `kAudioUnitSubType_MultiChannelMixer` only the sound of the first added node comes out.

obs: i actually use filters on `sourceNodeCopy` to remove the freqs that will be compressed on the `souceNode` but to keep things short i omitted them.

Here's the code:

```
override func connectOutputBus(_ sourceOutputBusNumber: UInt32, ofNode  sourceNode: AUNode, toInputBus destinationInputBusNumber: UInt32, ofNode destinationNode: AUNode, in graph: AUGraph!) throws {

  let sourceNodeCopy = sourceNode //original node without the harsh freq

  //create a filter for the harsh frequencies
  var filterDescription = AudioComponentDescription()
  filterDescription.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Effect
  filterDescription.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_BandPassFilter
  filterDescription.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple
  filterDescription.componentFlags = 0
  filterDescription.componentFlagsMask = 0

  AUGraphAddNode(graph, &filterDescription, &filterNode!) // Add the filter node
  AUGraphNodeInfo(graph, filterNode!, nil, &filterUnit!) // Get the Audio Unit from the node
  AudioUnitInitialize(filterUnit!) // Initialize the audio unit
  // Set filter params
  AudioUnitSetParameter(filterUnit!, kBandpassParam_CenterFrequency, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, 10038, 0)

  //create a processor to compress the frequency
  var dynamicProcessorDescription = AudioComponentDescription()
  dynamicProcessorDescription.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Effect
  dynamicProcessorDescription.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_DynamicsProcessor
  dynamicProcessorDescription.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple
  dynamicProcessorDescription.componentFlags = 0
  dynamicProcessorDescription.componentFlagsMask = 0

  // Add the dynamic processor node
  AUGraphAddNode(graph, &dynamicProcessorDescription, &dynamicProcessorNode)
  AUGraphNodeInfo(graph, dynamicProcessorNode, nil, &dynamicProcessorUnit)
  AudioUnitInitialize(dynamicProcessorUnit!)

  // Set compressor params
  AudioUnitSetParameter(dynamicProcessorUnit!, kDynamicsProcessorParam_Threshold, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, -35, 0)
  AudioUnitSetParameter(dynamicProcessorUnit!, kDynamicsProcessorParam_AttackTime, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, 0.02, 0)
  AudioUnitSetParameter(dynamicProcessorUnit!, kDynamicsProcessorParam_ReleaseTime, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, 0.04, 0)
  AudioUnitSetParameter(dynamicProcessorUnit!, kDynamicsProcessorParam_HeadRoom, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, 0, 0)

  //mixer
  var mixerDescription = AudioComponentDescription()
  mixerDescription.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Mixer
  mixerDescription.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_MultiChannelMixer
  mixerDescription.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple
  mixerDescription.componentFlags = 0
  mixerDescription.componentFlagsMask = 0

  AUGraphAddNode(graph, &mixerDescription, &audioEffectsController.mixerNode)
  AUGraphNodeInfo(graph, audioEffectsController.mixerNode, nil,
                    &audioEffectsController.mixerUnit)
  AudioUnitInitialize(audioEffectsController.mixerUnit!)

  AudioUnitSetParameter(mixerUnit!, kMultiChannelMixerParam_Volume, kAudioUnitScope_Input, 0, 1.0, 0);
    AudioUnitSetParameter(mixerUnit!, kMultiChannelMixerParam_Volume, kAudioUnitScope_Output, 0, 1.0, 0);


  //connect the nodes
  AUGraphConnectNodeInput(graph, sourceNode, sourceOutputBusNumber, filterNode, 0)
  AUGraphConnectNodeInput(graph, filterNode, sourceOutputBusNumber, dynamicProcessorNode, 0)

  AUGraphConnectNodeInput(graph, sourceNodeCopy, sourceOutputBusNumber, mixerNode, 0)
  AUGraphConnectNodeInput(graph, fiterNode, sourceOutputBusNumber, mixerNode, 0)

  //connect the mixer to the output
  AUGraphConnectNodeInput(graph, audioEffectsController.mixerNode, 0, destinationNode, destinationInputBusNumber)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you connect the node like this

```
AUGraphConnectNodeInput(graph, sourceNodeCopy, sourceOutputBusNumber, mixerNode, 0)
AUGraphConnectNodeInput(graph, fiterNode, sourceOutputBusNumber, mixerNode, 0)
```

If you do this, you will connect `sourceNodeCopy` and `filterNode` to the same input (0) of the `MixerNode`. But only one can be connected...

You should try this instead

```
AUGraphConnectNodeInput(graph, sourceNodeCopy, sourceOutputBusNumber, mixerNode, 0)
AUGraphConnectNodeInput(graph, fiterNode, sourceOutputBusNumber, mixerNode, 1)
```

Comment: I managed to make it work by using a splitter node and connection them like you said, thanks!

Comment: in the original question code where is 'filterNode' declared?  This code doesn't work.

Comment: @mafarja it may be a member variable. Usually you keep your main nodes as member